# Crashlytics works on production but doesn't work on test

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

It's a weird situation. I have a react native app that has a test and production environment. On the production side, my app is correctly integrated with crashlytics. But when I try to integrate on test apk, I see only **"App detected and we're waiting for a crash!"**
[SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlFmH.jpg)
Test and prod use the same application, the only difference is google-service.json files. I've not found anything. Please help.

Some notes:

- I've tried on emulator and physical devices.
- When I try to see dashboard for prod build, I can see correctly.
- I don't think that it is related by package versions(Because it works on prod). So I didn't put those.
- I 've seen " Crashlytics automatic data collection DISABLED by API" with adb logcat -s FirebaseCrashlytics command

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had mistakenly switched off Crashlytics for `DEBUG`. Crashlytics needs to be explicitly switched back on again because it will remember the boolean flag across app instances.

```
 if (kDebugMode) {
    await FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

When running the app, if you see the "App detected and we're waiting for a crash!" message, that means that the SDK was able to connect with the back end. But something could be preventing the SDK from sending crashes.

The first thing to do would be checking if the mapping file contains the parameter `firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled` and if it is set to false.  Check this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=android#enable-reporting).

If so, you can override this parameter opting in with the code:

```java
Firebase.crashlytics.setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true)
```